# Visual composer custom headline showing in post excerpt

Tags: css, wordpress

On the homepage of my wordpress site, my recent posts are displayed.

The post title on the homepage is taken from the posts title box at the top of the wordpress post editor, this title is hidden on the actual post page, in order to use a visual composer custom headline instead.
The css to hide the title on post pages is implemented site-wide from the themes custom css area.

On the homepage, the recent post area displays the before mentioned title and an excerpt from the post. The excerpt includes the visual composer custom headline as part of the excerpt text, this is what I'd like to remove.

Ideally looking for a scalable solution that doesn't require any code on a post by post basis.

This is what I'm using to not display the default post title within the post:

```
.single h1.entry-title {
    display:none;
}
```

The default post title still displays on the homepage, which is fine.

This is the visual composer custom headline shortcode:

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][custom_headline type="left" level="h2" looks_like="h1"]This is the visual composer title[/custom_headline][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][text_output]
```

I've tried modifying the level value (from "h1" to "h2") to see if the home page feed would then discount it, it didn't.

I've also experimented with adding a class value to the custom headline, then looked for a css tutorial on how to reference it and stop it from being displayed in excerpts or even just the homepage alone (keeping in mind it will still need to be displayed within the actual post)

Given that my css and programming knowledge, in general, extends to copy and paste snippets backed by a tutorial on how and where to implement, I haven't found anything for such a specific issue.

Comment: Welcome, we'd need to see some code to help you solve your problem. What have you tried so far, where do you fail? A little more info, please.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've made an edit to the original post with some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this issue.

It isn't code based. There are wordpress native settings to set a an explicit excerpt, so you can define exactly what will be presented.

- Navigate to the edit post section you want to set an excerpt for
- Click the "screen Options" button, currently located in the top right area of wordpress.
- Tick the "Excerpt" box
- Scroll down the page, until you find the excerpt section
- Click and edit the box with desired text